# Running a Scrapy Crawler

Tags: python, scrapy

I am very new in Python and Scrapy and I have written a crawler in PyCharm as follow:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http    import Request
import re

class TutsplusItem(scrapy.Item):
  title = scrapy.Field()



class MySpider(Spider):
  name = "tutsplus"
  allowed_domains   = ["bbc.com"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.bbc.com/"]

  def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()

# We stored already crawled links in this list
crawledLinks = []

for link in links:
  # If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
  #if linkPattern.match(link) and not link in crawledLinks:
  if not link in crawledLinks:
    link = "http://www.bbc.com" + link
    crawledLinks.append(link)
    yield Request(link, self.parse)

titles = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "media__link")]/text()').extract()
for title in titles:
  item = TutsplusItem()
  item["title"] = title
  print("Title is : %s" %title)
  yield item
```

However, when I run above codes,  nothing prints on the screen!  What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in a text file, name it to something like `your_spider.py` and run the spider using the `runspider` command:

```
scrapy runspider your_spider.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You would typically start scrapy using [scrapy crawl](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#crawl), which will hook everything up for you and start the crawling.

It also looks like your code is not properly indented (only one line inside `parse` when they all should be).

Answer (score 0):

To run a spider from within Pycharm you need to configure "Run/Debug configuration" properly. Running `your_spider.py` as a standalone script wouldn't result in anything.

As mentioned by @stranac `scrapy crawl` is the way to go. With `scrapy` being a binary and `crawl` an argument of your binary.

**Configure Run/Debug**

In the main menu go to :
*Run > Run Configurations...*

- Find the appropriate scrapy binary within your virtualenv and set its absolute path as **Script**.
  This should look like something like this:
  */home/username/.virtualenvs/your_virtualenv_name/bin/scrapy*
- In **Scrapy parameters** set up the parameters the binary `scrapy` will execute. In your case, you wan to start your spider. this is how this should look like:

`crawl your_spider_name` e.g. `crawl tutsplus`

- Make sure that the **Python intrepreter** is the one where you setup `Scrapy` and other packages needed for your project.
- Make sure that the **working directory** is the directory containing `settings.py`which is also generated by `Scrapy`.

From now on you should be able to Run and Debug your spiders from within Pycharm.